# How to I determine XLIFF serialized id?

Tags: xml, xliff

I'm trying to create a script that automatically places XLIFF in-line elements into <target> elements. Starting from the beginning, I have these HTML texts:

```
EN: The <b>big black</b> cat sleeps.
ES: El <b>gran</b> gato <b>negro</b> duerme.
```

When converted to XLIFF, they become:

```
<source lang="EN">The <g id="1">big black</g> cat sleeps.</source>
<target lang="ES:>El <g id="1">gran</g> gato <g id="1">negro</g> duerme.</target>
```

The XLIFF 1.2 spec says, "The value of the id element is determined by the tool creating the XLIFF document." So, is the above example that repeats the "=1" value acceptable, or should I increment it to "=2"?

Answer (score 2):

You should keep all `ids` as they are. Target `ids` should match to source `ids`. If you change it, there could be a problem when creating translated html file from target.

Comment: So is his/here example correct or not? (he/she is not modifying an XLIFF as I understand it, but generating XLIFF files with an house‑made program).